# Inconsistent webfont sizes in Android device

Tags: android, html, css

I am facing this haunting issue of different "p tag" font sizes across my website when all the pages use the same "p tag". This problem is specific to Android or possibly all mobile devices. Please see below screenshot comparison for better understanding.

The pages in question are: 
**Page 1** – http://drearth.in/about-dr-earth.html
**Page 2** – http://drearth.in/variants.html

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks!

BK Suru

Comment: in your html page p tag font size both is same no any issue

Comment: okay... so where do you see a problem?